# Use 'await' in parameter default in an async function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I want to use an async function as a default parameter but I get an error: `'await' is not a valid idientifier name in an async function`. Is this a language limitation or have I missed something?

**Background**

There is support for using functions to default parameters in a pretty neat way:

```
> a = ({ no }, b = (function(c) { return c -1; })(no)) => console.log(no,b);
[Function: a]
> a({ no: 2 })
2 1
```

This could allow for passing results from expensive database calls while retaining the option of getting the parameters if null. This requires though that we can do an await inside the parameter call:

```
> a = async ({ no }, b = await (async function(c) { return c -1; })(no)) => console.log(no,b);
a = async ({ no }, b = await (async function(c) { return c -1; })(no)) => console.log(no,b);
                       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: 'await' is not a valid identifier name in an async function
```

I suppose that this is a feature from async/await being syntactic sugar for Promises and rewriting the above as a `Promise` would be rather challenging. Still, the pattern would be really neat and If I've missed something, please enlighten me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a limitation, specifically in this case [*AwaitExpression* is not allowed in *CoverCallExpressionAndAsyncArrowHead*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-async-arrow-function-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors) (which includes the formal parameters). The second bullet point is:

> - It is a Syntax Error if *CoverCallExpressionAndAsyncArrowHead* Contains *AwaitExpression* is true.

...but the same language is present for the various other function definitions.

I probably don't have to tell you that you can work around this by just not awaiting the async function until within the body:

```js
const a = async ({ no }, b = (async function(c) { return c -1; })(no)) => {
// Removed await ------------^
    b = await b; // <== Then added it back within the function body
    console.log(no,b);
};
a({no: 3});
```

---

Using an `await` expression in a default parameter is a fascinating thought. I suspect the reason it's not (yet?) allowed is primarily complexity management. (This is speculation on my part, take it with a grain of salt.) The beginning of an `async` function is synchronous (that's how you start your asynchronous operation, after all), it only becomes async as of the first `await` or `return` (or implicit return at the point of falling off the end of the function). Having it become async prior to the beginning of the function body adds a fair bit of complexity. Not that it *couldn't* be done. :-)

**However**, looking through the closed issues on [the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait), [an issue](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait/issues/35) was raised asking what happens when a default parameter initialization throws an exception, should it throw or return a rejected promise? Which led to a TC39 discussion in which it was determined that it should return a rejected promise, thus [this issue](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait/issues/60), the resolution of which moved evaluation of the parameter initialization into the function body (so exceptions could be part of the promise). Which would seem, to my mind, to open up the possibility of allowing `await` in the formal parameters of an `async` function...

Comment: yeah, I got excited when I noticed that defaults could reference other input variables. The power of that is limited though unless you allow asynchronous calls. Do you know if this hasbeen discussed in the ECMAscript proposals https://github.com/tc39/proposals - it seems otherwise to be worthwhile adding. I saw your workaround - I'm familiar with it but it is a good point that await can be called regardless of `b` being a Promise or not. Excellent answer!

Comment: @MaxGordon: I haven't seen any discussion of it on the mailing list, but I was off the list for a few years because it was distracting me from other work (though on it for the time async functions were being completed). I don't see anything about this in the proposal's issues, but see the update I just added to the answer, there was something *else* in the issues which seems to open the door on this (to my mind).

Comment: Thanks for the deep dive into the TC39, if you or anyone more senior to me feels that this could be added you have my full support. My previous experience with mailing lists is that they require a lot of attention and since I'm primarily an MD I don't really feel that I will be able to make my voice heard.

Comment: @MaxGordon: "more senior" - ha! I'm not more senior than anyone else in the JS community. (Although I may well be *literally* more senior -- read: older -- than you are... :-) )